# Redirect oAuth Post to another domain

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, redirect

We have an SSO gateway page that works with oAuth 1.0 (the version LTI Learning Managements Systems use.) We are about to change the domain where this gateway is located.  But because a lot of customers might not immediately update their links, we want to have a redirect on the old domain to the new page.  Because this uses POST data, we need to pass this POST data to the new location.  I've tried using cURL as well as a simple javascript repost (capturing all the POST parameters and then putting them back into a form and automatically posting).  In both cases, it appears the post data is being passed properly.  But the outh_signature is not matching, so we are getting a verification failure.

When using the javascript repost method, I printed out the post data as it hit the redirect page and as it hit the oAuth SSO page.  The POST data was absolutely identical.  So I can't figure out why oAuth would fail. There is nothing in the POST data about referer page.  I do see some references in the oAuth library about HTTP_REFERER.  So could the problem be that the original page creating the signature has a different URL than the redirect page which is doing the referring?  I did try to manually set the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] value to the original referrer, but this didn't resolve the issue.

In case you are wondering, we can't simply place an informational page on the old URL since the users who access by SSO aren't the ones who set up the link. (People are linking through applications, not from a web page we control)  And I don't know if it would make a difference anyway, but we can't change oAuth versions since this is the one used by LTI.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After going further in the oAuth code, I did confirm that the referral uri is relevant.  The base string that the SSO page uses to create the signature includes the uri.  The application submitting the SSO request uses the uri it is sending the request TO.  Normally, these are the same.  In the case we set up, they can now be different.  So I just need to put something in the code to modify the base string.